# Suppress output of MKLINK /J?

Tags: windows, batch, symbolic-link, mklink

I am looking to have a batch file, where it suppresses the `mklink` output. I do not want the user to see the path.

I was able to do this with `> nul` and `robocopy`.

```
mklink /J "newpath" "originalpath"
```

is what the sample code looks like.

I basically have an interface where users can execute batch files, but they should not see the source code. They should just be able to click an icon and execute the file. It creates over 40 symbolic links with the click of the icon, and if some of the links exist it will show a warning

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Is there any way to suppress this notification and hide the warnings?

Comment: How about `2> nul`?

Answer (score 2):

> **I am looking to have a batch file, where it suppresses the mlink output, i do not want the user to see the path. Is there anyway to
>   suppress this warning and hide the warnings?**

Absolutely there are a few simple things that will help (use all or any combination if needed):

1. Use [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) ensuring that `@ECHO OFF` is set at least on the line above the [`MKLink`](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) command
2. Use [EXIST](https://ss64.com/nt/exist.html) ensuring the `IF NOT EXIST "newpath"` precedes the `mklink /J "newpath" "originalpath"` command on that same line.
3. Use [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) properly to redirect the `mklink /J "newpath" "originalpath"` command to `> NUL` just as you've used in the past.
4. Use [CLS](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html) right on the very next line after the `mklink /J "newpath" "originalpath" > NUL` command to clear the screen and any output from the command run before.
5. Use [EXIT](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) right on the very next line after the `mklink /J "newpath" "originalpath" > NUL` command (or after `CLS`).

Essentially what this does is tell it to only show command output on the screen, only run the `MKLink` command if the `"newpath"` does NOT already exist, if the `"newpath"` does not exist then redirect the `MKLink` command to `nul` which ensures it's not on the screen, clear the screen after the `MKLink` command (whether it's run or not), and then immediately exit and close the command window.

**Batch Script**

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST "newpath" MKLINK /J "newpath" "originalpath" > NUL
CLS
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [EXIST](https://ss64.com/nt/exist.html)
- [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [CLS](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html)
- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)